# How come I earned Ho Ho Ho hat on December 24?

Tags: support, winter-bash

It's **2:08 PM** 
Tuesday, December 24, 2013 (UTC)
*Time in Coordinated Universal Time*

How come I earned [Ho Ho Ho hat](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/ho-ho-ho) when it is supposed to be awarded for 
 **post or vote on December 25**?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/off-by-twelve-error-and-i-feel-fine-hat (but on MSU, so meh)

Answer (score 5):

"*SE over-awarded the hat so that people in Auckland / Tokyo / Shanghai / Vanuatu wouldn't have to wait until their midday to receive it.*"

It's already 25th on the mentioned places.

[reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159748).